# How can I get all records that return True in a model function in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class AuthorizedDriver < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  def authorized?
    !self.authorized_until.nil? && self.authorized_until.to_date >= Time.current.to_date
  end
end
```

I would like to be able to do:

```
def show_authorized_drivers
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  @authorized_drivers = @car.authorized_drivers.where(authorized?: true)
end
```

I know I can do this with a specific field, but I would like to use the `authorized?` function (or another function at a later time) above.

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated, thanks!

I am using Rails 4.1.4 and Ruby 2.1.2.

Comment: `where` is a query method. It's used to generate SQL that will be ran against your table. So naturally you can't do something like that with where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to your `Driver` model:

```
scope :authorized, -> { where('authorized_until >= ?', Time.current) }
```

Then you can query authorized drivers for a car like this:

```
@authorized_drivers = @car.authorized_drivers.authorized
```

---

Update (to answer your comment): You have two options if you need to add another criteria.

You could combine both conditions into one scope:

```
scope :authorized, -> { 
  where('authorized_until >= ?', Time.current).where(status: 'Active')
}
```

Or you could add another scope:

```
scope :active, -> { where(status: 'Active') }
```

and just chain the scopes:

```
@authorized_drivers = @car.authorized_drivers.authorized.active
```

Comment: I do not want to use this method because I may change the `authorized?` method to have additional criteria.

Comment: Why not just handle change that in that scope? Otherwise you need to use the approach @stoodfarback suggested. But be aware that is might be much slower, since it needs to load all drivers into memory first.

Comment: @jackerman09 That won't be a problem if you have proper tests for both the scope and the instance method. Ten minutes of effort writing the tests now can easily save you from a disaster later.

Comment: Thanks, so would I still be able to use `scope` if I wanted to add another criteria, e.g. `&& self.status == 'Active'`?

Comment: @jackerman09: I updated my answer to also the question from your comment.

Comment: @spickermann, thanks! What about the fact that I was using `authorized_until.to_date` (the field is originally a time), will this be a problem?

Comment: Depends on your data. If it really need to be converted to date (because the database might handle it differently), then change the query to `'Date(authorized_until) >= ?'` or use `Time.current.beginning_of_day` instead of just `Time.current`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like so:

```
@authorized_drivers = @car.authorized_drivers.to_a.select(&:authorized?)
```

Note that this fetches all the `authorized_drivers` for that car, then filters them by calling the `#authorized?` method.

Also note that

```
.select(&:authorized?)
```

is shortcut notation for

```
.select {|it| it.authorized? }
```

Comment: You don't need to use `to_a`. :)

Comment: @limekin True. However, I usually add it there to make it clear that we are done with the arel stuff, just filtering a simple array. For example, `#select` is an arel method as well, and has meaning in the context of sql.

Comment: Ah that's good, alright then. Btw, I think you can also try adding an example of how the callable block is passed into `show_authorized_drivers`. (I was really going to post an answer similar to yours along with that kind of example, but didn't mind to after I saw yours :D)